# Transformar chr em time no R

Tags: r

Gostaria de transformar a variável "Hora" (que está no formato chr) em formato de hora. Os dados estão assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 2):

Há vários pacotes que lidam com formato de horas no R. `lubridate` é provavelmente o mais amigável atualmente.

```
horas <- paste0(1:18,':00')

> horas
 [1] "1:00"  "2:00"  "3:00"  "4:00"  "5:00"  "6:00"  "7:00"  "8:00"  "9:00" 
[10] "10:00" "11:00" "12:00" "13:00" "14:00" "15:00" "16:00" "17:00" "18:00"

> class(horas)
[1] "character"

library(lubridate)
horas.ld <- hm(horas)

> horas.ld
 [1] "1H 0M 0S"  "2H 0M 0S"  "3H 0M 0S"  "4H 0M 0S"  "5H 0M 0S"  "6H 0M 0S" 
 [7] "7H 0M 0S"  "8H 0M 0S"  "9H 0M 0S"  "10H 0M 0S" "11H 0M 0S" "12H 0M 0S"
[13] "13H 0M 0S" "14H 0M 0S" "15H 0M 0S" "16H 0M 0S" "17H 0M 0S" "18H 0M 0S"

> class(horas.ld)
[1] "Period"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"

> horas.ld[7] - horas.ld[1]
[1] "6H 0M 0S"
```

Para quem gosta de usar `data.table`, ele possui classes próprias para data e hora:

```
library(data.table)

> as.ITime(horas)
 [1] "01:00:00" "02:00:00" "03:00:00" "04:00:00" "05:00:00" "06:00:00"
 [7] "07:00:00" "08:00:00" "09:00:00" "10:00:00" "11:00:00" "12:00:00"
[13] "13:00:00" "14:00:00" "15:00:00" "16:00:00" "17:00:00" "18:00:00"

> class(as.ITime(horas))
[1] "ITime"
```

Comment: @erick-kill Os dados de exemplo para sua pergunta são fáceis de gerar, mas fica o conselho: sempre poste um exemplo dos seus dados em um formato que seja facilmente reproduzível.